# R: Annualize rolling quaterly returns

Tags: r

I am new to R and have a quite basic question I guess. I couldn't find help for my specific issue.

I have a data frame consisting of two columns. The first indicating the year and quarter (e.g. 19901, 19902, 19903 etc.). The second shows the corresponding quarterly return.

Now, I want to annualize the returns. As a result I want to have a data.frame with only a year column and the corresponding annualized return.

I know there is the function Return.annualized from the ‘PerformanceAnalytics’ package. However, this function does not calculate rolling annualized returns.

Is there a nice package or function that could solve my problem?

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page on how to ask a question.  in particular the question requires some data in reproducible form.  Also questions which ask to locate a function are normally closed as opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

If you have log returns, they exhibit the nice advantage of being summable over time.

If that's the case you can simply apply a rolling window that sums the four previous quarters.

Let's assume you have a vector or list with quarterly log returns called `q_ret`

```
library('zoo')


an_ret <- rollapply(q_ret, 4, sum)
```

Note, that from a finance perspective, this does not hold with simple returns.